# manageable way to handle exceptions in java

Tags: java, spring, exception, ibatis, dao

I am trying to come up with a manageable way to handle exceptions in a DAO.  Typically a method in my DAO looks like this:

```
public ArrayList fetchColors (String id)
{
    //call iBatis SqlMapClient
    //put results in a list
    //return list
}
```

If an error happens in the above code then everything is written to `server.log` and on the front page I show custom error screen.  However, I want to avoid to put the stacktrace to server.log but instead write it to `my_app.log` (I'm using log4j).

So I'm planning to transform above method to following:

```
public ArrayList fetchColors (String id) throws SqlException
{
    try {
    //call iBatis SqlMapClient
    //put results in a list
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
      logger.log (e);
      throws e;
    }
    //return list
}
```

**Questions:**

- Is this the best way to approach the problem?
- I have lot of methods in the DAO and doing the above for each method will be a PITA..Is there an easier way to do this so same thing applies to all the methods in a DAO?

Comment: Seems to me this is the best way to do it. Java is just a very verbose language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A '**callback**' solution in order to handle exception and log in one place:

```
interface CallBack{
    void invoke();
}
```

Define a skeleton method like:

```
//Skeleton to handle exception and log in one place 
public void doBusiness(CallBack callBack)  throws SqlException{
    try{
        callBack.invoke();
    }catch(SqlExceptione){
        logger.log (e);
        throws e;
    }
}
```

Call it like:

```
public ArrayList fetchColors (String id) throws SqlException{
    doBusiness(new CallBack(){

        public void invoke() {
               //call iBatis SqlMapClient
               //put results in a list     
            }        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use AOP here. For example:

```
<bean id="exceptionLogger" class="my.good.ExceptionLogger" />  
<aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="allDaoMethods" expression="execution(* my.dao.*(..))" />

        <aop:aspect id="daoLogger" ref="exceptionLogger">
            <aop:after-throwing pointcut-ref="allDaoMethods"
                                method="logIt"
                                throwing="e"/>
        </aop:aspect>  
    </aop:config>
```

Also as a side note you should always log like this so that you can see the stack trace in the log file.

> logger.log (e,e);

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you add some [method logging with Spring AOP](http://www.earldouglas.com/node/20).  As CoolBeans showed, you can simply use an @AfterThrowing advice.